# Local notification sound not playing in iPhone 4S with iOS7

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I have one issue with my app, When receive alert local notification the sound not playing in **iPhone 4s (iOS 7)(phone is locked)** but work in **iPod(ios 6.1.6)** and **iPhone 5(iOS 8)**. i use the following code..

```
// Schedule the notification

UILocalNotification* localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc]init];
localNotification.fireDate = itemDate;
NSLog(@"%@",index);
if (appDelegate().check == 0) {
    [self repetationType:index Notification:localNotification];
}

//setting repetation type
//UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName

localNotification.soundName=@"Message Alert - Happy.wav";
NSString *str=[NSString stringWithString:NSLocalizedString(@"youhave", nil)];

localNotification.alertBody=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",str,reminName];//remindtext;
NSLog(@"%@",localNotification.alertBody);
localNotification.alertAction = NSLocalizedString(@"item", nil);
localNotification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
// localNotification.applicationIconBadgeNumber=[[UIApplication sharedApplication]applicationIconBadgeNumber]+1;
localNotification.applicationIconBadgeNumber=1;

NSString *alarm=[[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%@",reminName];
// NSDictionary *userDict=[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:image,@"info",nil];
NSDictionary *userDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:alarm forKey:@"info"];
NSLog(@"userDict=%@",userDict);
localNotification.userInfo=userDict;

[[UIApplication sharedApplication]scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you forget to add this line in your code

```
     [localNotification setSoundName:UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName]
```

Comment: keyur i add the custom sound..like  localNotification.soundName=@"Message Alert - Happy.wav";

Comment: @user3725874 Make sure the sound is actually in your app’s bundle, is in the correct format (linear PCM or IMA4—pretty much anywhere that explains how to convert sounds for iOS will tell you how to do that), and is under 30 seconds.

Comment: yes i add the file in app's bundle and it is play in ipod and iphone 5 but not play in iphone 4s only

Comment: I hope sound button and volume is on...:)

Comment: i check it. sound button and volume is on

Comment: can you please check with default sound it will be play or not?

Comment: keyur any issue with the version because sound perfectly play in my ipod (ios 6.1.6)

Comment: NO I think not. have you check that system sound is play or not?

Answer (score 0):

If your notification works well in other iOS devices, then it should also works in 4S.

Notification sound will not differ depends on the device or OS version. So problem lies in the device settings.

Make sure you enabled the notification **sounds** in the device settings

[image]